# How to solve an equation with variables in a matrix in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

i'm coding in Pyhon, and I'm working on stereo-correlation. I want to resolve this equation : m = K.T.M

m,K,M are know.

where :

**M** is the  homogeneous coordinate of a point in the cartesian coordinate system "world"

```
M=np.array([X,Y,Z,1])
```

**K** is my intrinsic matrix for the left camera

```
K=np.matrix([ [fx,  0, cx, 0],
              [ 0, fy, cy, 0], 
              [ 0,  0,  1, 0]])
```

**m** its the M point views by the left camera

```
m=np.array([x,y,1])
```

and **T** is the transformation to pass to the "world" coordinate system to the left camera coordinate system.

```
T= np.matrix([[x00, x01, x02, Tx],
              [x10, x11, x12, Ty], 
              [x20, x21, x22, Tz], 
              [0  , 0  , 0  , 1 ]])
```

So I want to solve this equation to find **T** but it's impossible to create a matrice without give values to variables.

someone have a solution?

Thanks
best regards

Comment: What is `K.T.M` in your formula?? Dot-product?

Comment: You only have three equations, and twelve unknowns, so there is no unique soution.  I suspect that the `x_ij` entries in your transformation matrix are supposed to be a rotation, which would bring you down to six unknowns, still too many.

Comment: Yes, I know i have only 3 equations for 12 variables, but if i take an other points of my patterns, so an other M like M(1,1,0), I obtain 3 news equations. My problem was the fact to introduce variables without values in a matrix. But I think @Dietrich have solved my problem, i will test that.

Comment: @Monkpit K.T.M is just a product of matrix and vector

Comment: @SvenMarnach, yes the transformation is composed of rotation _xij_ and translation _Ti_, but i don't have a simple rotation around a single axis. This rotation could be compose of succesion of rotations around differents axis

Answer (score 2):

If you want a generic solution, you can use [Sympy](http://www.sympy.org), which allows you to work with symbolic expression. In the following code the expression `K.T.M = m` is reformulated to a standard linear equation `HH.xx = mm`, where `xx` is the vector with the unknowns extracted from `T`:

```
from IPython.display import display
import sympy as sy

sy.init_printing()  # LaTeX like pretty printing for IPython

# declaring symbolic variables:
x, y, X, Y, Z, fx, fy, cx, cy = sy.symbols("x y X Y Z f_x f_y c_x c_y", real=True)
x00, x01, x02, x10, x11 = sy.symbols("x00, x01, x02, x10, x11", real=True)
x12, x20, x21, x22 = sy.symbols("x12, x20, x21, x22", real=True)
Tx, Ty, Tz = sy.symbols(" T_x T_y T_z", real=True)

# Building matrices and vectors:
M = sy.Matrix([X, Y, Z, 1])
m = sy.Matrix([x, y, 1])
K = sy.Matrix([[fx,  0, cx, 0],
               [0,  fy, cy, 0],
               [0,   0,  0, 1]])
T = sy.Matrix([[x00, x01, x02, Tx],
               [x10, x11, x12, Ty],
               [x20, x21, x22, Tz],
               [0,     0,   0,  1]])

print("KTM = K.T.M = ")
KTM = sy.simplify(K*T*M)
display(KTM)

print("Vector of Unkowns xx.T = ")
xx = sy.Matrix(list(T.atoms(sy.Symbol)))
display(xx.T)
print("For equation HH.xx = mm, HH = ")
HH = KTM[:2, :].jacobian(xx)  # calculate the derivative for each unknown
display(HH)
```

As @Sven-Marnach already noted, there are not enough equations for a unique solution. Since the last row of the vector `KTM` and of `m` is 1, there are only two equations for twelve variables.

If you have multiple pixelsto evaluate, i.e., multiple pairs of `(m, M)`, you can use [Numpy's Least Squares Solver](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) to find a solution.

Comment: Yes, my pattern is composed of 45 points so i have lot of pairs of (m, M), so more equations than variables. @Dietrich thanks a lot for your answer and your help. I will try it and coming back to you.