# How to solve a matrix equation for an unknown matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matrix, camera

[image: Camera Calibration and 3D reconstruction using opencv]

I am trying solving the [equation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) , s m' = A[R|t]M'

i.e

**m = K . T . M** where **m, K, M** and last column of **T [ R | t ]** are known.

I want to obtain the values for each element of the 3*3 rotation matrix. I have.

This question was also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204155/how-to-solve-an-equation-with-variables-in-a-matrix-in-python)

But I could not understand how to get values for 3*3 rotation matrix after making the new set of equations each time, when we take new values for **m** and **M**.

**m** contains the coordinates of the projection point in pixels, I have 16 different points on the image for the pattern captured by the camera and have 16 set of values for each u and v.

```
m=np.array([u,v,1])
```

**K** is my intrinsic matrix/camera matrix/matrix of intrinsic parameters for the camera, I have the value for fx, fy (focal lengths) and cx, cy (principal point) as camera intrinsic matrix

```
K=np.matrix([ [fx, 0, cx, 0], 
              [ 0, fy, cy, 0], 
              [ 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

**T** is the transformation to pass to the "world" coordinate system to the camera coordinate system  **( extrinsic matrix,[ R  | t ] )**, I also have the values for Tx, Ty and Tz.

```
T= np.matrix([[x00, x01, x02, Tx], 
              [x10, x11, x12, Ty], 
              [x20, x21, x22, Tz], 
              [0 , 0 , 0 , 1 ]])
```

**M** is the homogeneous coordinate of a point in the Cartesian coordinate system "world" i.e the coordinates of a 3D point in the world coordinate space. I have the 16 points from the pattern therefore i have 16 different values for each X, Y, Z.

```
M=np.array([X,Y,Z,1])
```

My goal is to get the values for elements x00, x01, x02, x10, x11, x12, x20, x21, x22 for matrix **T**. could someone please help??

**For more clarification:**

Suppose for **m**  matrix (the coordinates of the projection point in pixels) the value of u and v are:

**u** = [ 337,  337, 316, 317, 302, 302, 291, 292, 338, ...]

and

**v** =[ 487, 572, 477, 547, 470, 528, 465, 516, 598, ...]

i.e the coordinates of the first projection point in pixels are **337** (row number) and **487** (column number)

therefore,

for first set of equation, matrix, **m**  will have values,

```
import sympy as sy            
import numpy as np


# m = sy.Matrix([u, v, 1]
m = sy.Matrix([337, 487, 1])
```

**,**

for second set of equation, matrix, **m**  will have values,

```
# m = sy.Matrix([u, v, 1]
m = sy.Matrix([337, 572, 1])
```

and soon...

for **K** matrix (matrix of intrinsic parameters) the values:

```
K = sy.Matrix([[711.629,  0, 496.220, 0],
               [0,  712.682, 350.535, 0],
               [0,   0,  0, 1]])
```

for **M** matrix ( the coordinates of a 3D points in the world coordinate space) the value for X,Y and Z are:

```
X = [4.25, 4.25, 5.32, 5.32, 6.27, 6.27, 7.28, 7.28, 4.20, ...] 
Y = 0
Z =  [0.63, 1.63, 0.63, 1.63, 0.59, 1.59, 0.60, 1.92, 2.92, ...]
```

for first set of equation, matrix **M** will be

```
# M=np.array([X,Y,Z,1])
M = sy.Matrix([0.63, 0, 4.25, 1])
```

**,**

for second set of equation, matrix, **M**  will have values,

```
# M=np.array([X,Y,Z,1])
M = sy.Matrix([1.63, 0, 4.25, 1])
```

and soon...

for **T** matrix ( extrinsic matrix, [ R | t ])  we have value for **Tx, Ty, Tz** as 0,  -1.35, 0  .Therefore, T matrix will be:

```
T = sy.Matrix([[x11, x12, x13, 0],
               [x21, x22, x23, -1.32],
               [x31, x32, x33, 0],
               [0,     0,   0,  1]])
```

I need to make nine set of these matrix equations: **m = K * T * M** using different value for **m** and **M** so that I could calculate the values for 9 unknowns in **T** matrix out of these set of equations.

Comment: could you reformat the question so it's easier to read?

Comment: Do you want to index the matrix or calculate the matrix itself?

Comment: @Aditya thank you for your comment. I want to calculate the values of the T matrix, such that when we take a new value for the vector M i.e in world coordinate and  multiply the  K*T*M, it should give me the value of m i.e in camera coordinate,

Comment: Could you please include the equations from the opencv documentation as inline images? And may I suggest a more clear title: "How to solve a matrix equation for an unknown matrix?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, you have the matrix equation (using the notation of the OpenCV documentation):

```
A @ (R @ w + t) == m
```

Where `A.shape == (3, 3)`, `R.shape == (3, 3)`, `w.shape == (3, n)`, `t.shape == (3, 1)`, `m.shape == (3, n)`, representing `n` points in world coordinates `w` and image coordinates `m`.

This equation can be rearranged as

```
w.T @ R.T == (inv(A) @ m - t).T
```

where `inv(A)` is the inverse of `A`. The shape of the left- and right-hand sides is `(n, 3)`. This has the format of a matrix equation, with 9 unknowns (in R.T) and n equations. In this form, you can feed into `np.linalg.lstsq` for a least-squares solution - assuming that you have `n >= 3` with sufficiently independent points.

Here is a demonstration with random numbers:

```
import numpy as np

# Setup test case
np.random.seed(1)
R = np.random.randint(-9, 9, size=(3, 3)).astype(np.float64)
t = np.array([1, 1.5, 2]).reshape(3, 1) # column vector
Rt = np.hstack([R, t]) # shape (3, 4)
A = np.diag([0.5, 0.5, 1.0]) # shape (3, 3)

n = 20 # number of points
# M: shape (4, n)
M = np.vstack([np.random.uniform(size=(3, n)), np.ones((1, n))])
m = A @ Rt @ M # m.shape == (3, n)

# Now try to reconstruct R, given A, M, t, and m.

w = M[:3, :] # world XYZ coordinates, shape (3, n)

# Matrix equation: A @ (R @ w + t) == m
# Equivalent to w.T @ R.T == (inv(A) @ m - t).T
RTfit, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(w.T, (np.linalg.inv(A) @ m - t).T, rcond=None)

Rfit = np.around(RTfit.T, 6)
print(f'Original R:\n{R}\nReconstructed R:\n{Rfit}')
```

Output:

```
Original R:
[[-4.  2.  3.]
 [-1.  0.  2.]
 [-4.  6. -9.]]
Reconstructed R:
[[-4.  2.  3.]
 [-1. -0.  2.]
 [-4.  6. -9.]]
```

Note that you could also use an exact solve using three data points (`n=3`):

```
Rsolve = np.linalg.solve(w.T[:3], (np.linalg.inv(A) @ m[:, :3] - t).T).T
```

but in this case, you need to pick your three points carefully or it won't work.

Here is an attempt with your data:

```
t = np.array([[0, -1.32, 0]]).T
w = np.array([
    [4.25, 4.25, 5.32, 5.32, 6.27, 6.27, 7.28, 7.28, 4.20],
    np.zeros(9),
    [0.63, 1.63, 0.63, 1.63, 0.59, 1.59, 0.60, 1.92, 2.92]
    ])
m = np.array([
    [337, 337, 316, 317, 302, 302, 291, 292, 338],
    [487, 572, 477, 547, 470, 528, 465, 516, 598],
    np.ones(9)
    ])
A = np.array([
    [711.629,  0, 496.220],
    [712.682, 350.535, 0],
    [0, 0, 1]
    ])
RTfit, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(w.T, (np.linalg.inv(A) @ m - t).T, rcond=None)
Rfit = np.around(RTfit.T, 6)
print(Rfit)
```

Output:

```
array([[-0.040938,  0.      , -0.016044],
       [ 0.448038,  0.      ,  0.52933 ],
       [ 0.14251 ,  0.      ,  0.127464]])
```

It cannot meaningfully solve the middle column of the R matrix because all Y values of the input were zero. (If you try this with `np.linalg.solve`, you'll get a singular-matrix error.)

The fit is not particularly good, as evidenced by plotting `m` and `A @ (R @ w + t)`:

[image: xy coordinates of m: input versus fit]

The mismatch implies that there is no R matrix possible that is consistent with the data. In your comment, you ask whether the R matrix is the most optimal solution. It is the optimal solution in matching the LHS and the RHS of the equation (`w.T @ Rfit.T` versus `(inv(A) @ m - t).T`).

Given the large mismatch in the above plot, it doesn't make much sense to speculate on the accuracy of the resulting R matrix. It is likely that there is a problem with the input data; the points (m, w), the t-vector, or the A matrix.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have a query, I took your sample code to get the value of **R** as 3*3, when I take the single  value for **m** (337, 487, 1) as LHS (same as above i.e u,v) &  solve the RHS as **A .( R | t ) . w** with A as same, **R**  obtained from your code as an output & **t** as its 4th column i.e (R|t with size 3,4 ), using single value for w (X, Y, Z), making w as (4,1) vector as in equation from openCV documentation, with fourth row as 1 i.e w = (4.25, 0, 0.63, 1) .But after solving, I'm not getting LHS == RHS. I need to proof somehow that **R** matrix has the optimal values